# Changing background-attachment property on scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that has a background-image with the background-attachment as fixed. I change from fixed to scroll when the div with the background images is halfway using jQuery. I seem to have got it working however when I scroll down, there seems to be jump when the property is changed. How can I avoid this jump?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.service-logo').offset().top + halfHeight) {
    $('.service-logo').addClass('bg-scroll');
  } else {
    $('.service-logo').removeClass('bg-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content2 {
  background: black;
  height: 1000px;
}

.service-logo {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg-scroll {
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
}

.content3 {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>

<div class="content2 service-logo">

</div>


<div class="content3">

</div>
```

Comment: I have posted a solution for your problem please review it once, its work perfectly for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this script you will get perfect positioning with this code for any screen.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sectionHeight = $('.service-logo').height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.service-logo').offset().top + ((sectionHeight - windowHeight) / 2)) {
    $('.service-logo').addClass('bg-scroll');
  } else {
    $('.service-logo').removeClass('bg-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
}
.content2 {
  background: black;
  height: 1000px;
}
.service-logo {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-position: center;
}
.bg-scroll {
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
.content3 {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="content2 service-logo">
</div>
<div class="content3">
</div>
```

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this

```
background-position: center;
```

is causing a different calculation and not putting it exactly where you think it should go, based on a combination of the image height and `background-size`.

If you set the position to the middle of content2 manually, then it works smoothly:

```
      background-position: center 200px;
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //var halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.service-logo').offset().top) {
    $('.service-logo').addClass('bg-scroll');
  } else {
    $('.service-logo').removeClass('bg-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content2 {
  background: black;
  height: 1000px;
}

.service-logo {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-position: center 400px;
}

.bg-scroll {
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
}

.content3 {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content2 service-logo"></div>
<div class="content3"></div>
```

(snippet best run full page or via 'edit this snippet' - doesn't really work in the small snippet-run window)

Comment: Thank you. This wouldn't really work well for different screen sizes? Is there a way to automatically center the image rather then manually fixing it?

Comment: it is centred within .content2.  It didn't work on the tiny in-page snippet but worked fine on full page.  The issue is that `background-position: center` calculates a very slightly different position from your javascript.  You can tweak the js until it gets it exactly right (+/- a fixed offset based on the image size)